# Dynamically selecting a static embedded image?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

Here's my current situation:

I have images embedded on a class.

```
package system
{
    public class Embedded
    {
        [Embed(source="assets/srcorangeboxidle.png")]
        public static const btnSrcOrangeBoxIdle:Class;

        [Embed(source="assets/srcorangeboxpressed.png")]
        public static const btnSrcOrangeBoxPressed:Class;

        [Embed(source="assets/hl1idle.png")]
        public static const btnHL1Idle:Class;

        [Embed(source="assets/hl1pressed.png")]
        public static const btnHL1Pressed:Class;

        public function Embedded(){}
    }
}
```

Now on my main MXML file, I have the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import system.Embedded;

            protected function toggleButtonState(target:Object,pressed:Boolean=false):void
            {
                var baseImageName:String = target.id.toString();
                if (!pressed) {
                    target.source = Embedded.[baseImageName+"Idle"];
                } else {
                    target.source = Embedded.[baseImageName+"Pressed"];
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Image id="btnSrcOrangeBox" x="107" y="245" source="{Embedded.btnSrcOrangeBoxIdle}" mouseDown="toggleButtonState(btnSrcOrangeBox,true)" mouseUp="toggleButtonState(btnSrcOrangeBox,false)"/>
    <s:Image id="btnHL1" x="107" y="355" source="{Embedded.btnHL1Idle}" mouseDown="toggleButtonState(btnHL1,true)" mouseUp="toggleButtonState(btnHL1,false)"/>
</s:Application>
```

As you can tell, the above codes don't seem to do the trick. I just want to dynamically select which **Embedded.*** class to select. Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the dot after the class name. The following should work:

```
target.source = Embedded[baseImageName + "Idle"];
```

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed! If it's not asking too much, can you possibly post the documentation page stating this? I'm at a loss on what keyword to search for about this kind of thing. :)

Comment: But how did you find out how to do it?

Comment: I guess I read about it on stackoverflow a long time ago. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259249/get-a-static-property-from-class-in-actionscript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458719/flex-actionscript-dynamically-accessing-static-var

Comment: Wow, so there's no real documentation about it. I wonder how those guys figured it out. Anyway, thanks a lot man!

Comment: I looked at the question and realized its not my post which I was drafting. Exactly what I am looking for. I was messing up a lot with lot of other stuff such as **describeType**. But it is such a simple way to do. I hope this is not a hack. Stuppid adobe didn't document this.